# Isolated environment in singularity?

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, slurm, singularity-container

I'm running singularity on an HPC cluster. I want to have an isolated environment so I can do development without affecting my home directory.

### 1. Singularity on Cluster

I tried the simplest thing I could think of to run a singularity container:

singularity pull library://ubuntu:latest
singularity run ubuntu_latest.sif

However, my singularity shell is my home environment.

### 2. Docker on my laptop

docker run -it ubuntu:latest /pty/bash
I get an isolated ubuntu environment

### 3. Question:

How do I achieve 2. on my cluster?

Is the problem a "feature" of singularity or the way singularity is configured on my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar need and so far have found the following two approaches to isolate a Singularity environment as one expects of Docker. It is worth noting, however, that Singularity's philosophy differs from Docker's in that it favors "integration over isolation" [(per the user guide)](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/4.0/user-guide/security.html), and it is not meant to be used in the same way. Unfortunately for those of us who cannot use Docker in our production environments due to permission limitations, that means hacking together alternative solutions.

1. `--containall` flag [(manual entry)](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/4.0/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#using-no-home-and-containall-flags). Excludes everything in your host's home directory, not making it available to your container (as `--no-home` does) and limits access to the host as much as possible.

```
singularity shell --containall <container>.sif
```

2. `--no-mount` flag  [(manual entry)](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/4.0/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#disabling-system-binds). Introduced in Singularity 3.7, it allows you to exclude system mounts, meaning that you can mask system directories in your host's `/` and not make them available to the container. In my case, the container can see everything in `/` by default, and this can help manage it.

```
singularity run --no-mount <dirs to omit> <container>.sif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SIF file for development on a HPC (no `sudo`) you must be able to access from inside the container some files outside of it. The SIF file is not possibly to modify unless you convert it into sandbox, but that requires 'sudo`.

To do anything meaningful with your container you can use:

```
singularity shell --bind /path_on_hpc/devel_dir:/devel_dir_mount_in_container container.sif

cd /devel_dir_mount_in_container

# then you can develop, i.e.
vim foo.c
```

Be aware that bare bones SIF containers may not contain tools you want, so the trick is to build a sandbox on a machine you have sudo, install what you need, convert to SIF and then upload to HPC.